# What's the relationship between "free theorems" and "free objects"

Tags: algebra, parametricity

What's the relationship between [*free theorems*](https://www.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf) and [*free objects*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object) from algebra. They seem quite similar. I'm wondering if there's an underlying principle here.

Answer (score 7):

There is no relationship.  They both use the word "free", but with different meanings of the word "free".  It's just an accidental collision, which will happen when you have a language like English with a fixed number of words and the number of concepts we want to talk about exceeds the number of words in the language.

A *free group* is, roughly, a group that is about as generic as possible (it has no special structure).  Here, the word free means "having no non-trivial strucutre", i.e., free of special equalities.

In contrast, a *free theorem* about some code (e.g., a function) is one that follows automatically from the type signature of that code.  Here, the word free means "at no cost" or "with no extra reasoning about the code required"; it's an automatic consequence of the type signature, regardless of the implementation/code of the function.

Comment: and yet free objects are, in a sense, generated from the axioms. Free theorems are generated (as you say "follow automatically") from the type signature.